# Exterior Door Weather Stripping

Tags: doors, weather

So kind of a two fold question. We rent in a duplex, built in the 60s and never really updated. We have a front door with a gap on the bottom big enough to let light in and the weather stripping on the side is cracking and flaking. My roommate replaced the weather stripping with the same stripping they use for their camper shell and called it good. Is this okay or should we get weather stripping specifically for a door? Second, there are still ants coming in at the corners of the door. Any ideas for sealing these areas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome. Please ask only one question in each post. Take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Comment: Welcome! Is there any way that you could post pictures of the door, the threshold, and weatherstripping? We could better answer your question(s) if we could see what it all looks like.

Comment: Since you're renting, 1) I'd ask the landlord to fix the weather seal. After all, if water gets in, it's up to him to handle the repairs of the water damage, so it's in his best interest. 2) I'd ask the landlord to take care of the ant problem. If they're getting in, so can other bugs that can cause structural damage instead of just being "your" problem.

Answer (score 1):

Weather stripping is ok if 1) it stops the weather, and 2) it looks halfway decent. There's not much more to it than that.

Ants can't be stopped with weather stripping. There's *always* another way. I'd use some control granules outside the building and be sure there aren't any attractants inside.